# What is the best way to pass information to asynchronous methods in android?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

I'm developing a application for android in Android Studio, and I have I doubt about which of the methods below is better to pass information to asynchronous methods, like HTTP requests, for instance. I used as example a alert dialog:

First Method: Declare the parameters as final:

```
final String par1 = "Test";

DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which){
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                    //Yes button clicked
                    doSomething(par1);
                    break;

                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                    //No button clicked
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        MainActivity.getCurrentInstance().getApplicationContext()
    );
    builder.setMessage("confirm the operation?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
            .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();
```

Second method: pass to listener constructor:

```
MyOnClickListener dialogClickListener = new MyOnClickListener("test") {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which){
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                    //Yes button clicked
                    doSomething(this.getParameterValue());
                    break;

                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                    //No button clicked
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        MainActivity.getCurrentInstance().getApplicationContext()
    );
    builder.setMessage("confirm the operation?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
            .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();
```

I have a certain fear of the first method for it being a kind of global variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first method is fine. This is not a global variable, this is a local variable captured in-to a closure. Technically speaking, this works more or less the same way as if you have passed the variable in-to a constructor of the listener, stored it there and then used in the method. The difference is that compiler does all that for you and you can write less code.